# How to expand the matrix in Matlab (forming $A$ matrix in least square problem)

Tags: matlab, least-squares

If I have 5 data points (actually, this could be vary huge number):
$a = [1;2;3;4;5]$

To each data point, I can form a matrix $[a(i),2a(i)]$. (actually, I have to find the matrix, this matrix needs some calculation.)

For example, $[a(i)\times 2+3, 3\times a(i)cos \theta]$

Therefore, I can form 5 such matrices with different values.

Now, If I want to form a big matrix:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\2 & 4 \\3 &6 \\4&8\\5&10 \end{bmatrix}$.

One way to do it is by for-loop. Is there any compact way to do it? (If number of data points is very large).

---

I want to use this technique to form the $A$ matrix in the least square problem. And I have 200 measurements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood you well, but if you have:

- the data array $\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\
  x_{2}\\
  \vdots\\
  x_{n}
  \end{bmatrix}$
- the meassurements array $\mathbf{y}=\begin{bmatrix}y_{1}\\
  y_{2}\\
  \vdots\\
  y_{n}
  \end{bmatrix}$

you can create the matrix:
$$\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}x_{1} & y_{1}\\
x_{2} & y_{2}\\
\vdots & \vdots\\
x_{n} & y_{n}
\end{bmatrix}$$
just with the code:

> A = [ x, y ] ;

I hope it was usefull to you

Comment: No, this is not what I ask.  Since I have to find each row (not known before calculating), so I cannot pile up by hand. I edit my problem, hope it is more clear.

Comment: if the different rows don't follow any nice general formula the best thing you can use is a for-loop, but it's faster if matlab knows from the beggining the size of A, so it's faster if you add, A = zeros( N, 2 ) before the for-loop.